# macOS / BSD - add dir to locate database?

Tags: macos, bsd, locate

How do I add a directory to be indexed by `locate.updatedb` on macOS / BSD so that I can find files in that directory with the `locate` command?

I read the man page of `locate(1)` on Mac, but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

The `locate(1)` man page tells you how to use the `locate` command to look stuff up. As the indexing is done by `locate.updatedb`, you should read the `locate.updatedb(8)` man page instead.

But on a macOS Big Sur at least, the information relevant to your question is rather limited. Basically it just says:

> The contents of the newly built database can be controlled by the `/etc/locate.rc` file.

By default, all the settings in `/etc/locate.rc` seem to be commented out. The relevant lines for your question are:

```
# directories to be put in the database
#SEARCHPATHS="/"

# directories unwanted in output
#PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/tmp"

# filesystems allowed. Beware: a non-listed filesystem will be pruned
# and if the SEARCHPATHS starts in such a filesystem locate will build
# an empty database.
#
# be careful if you add 'nfs'
#FILESYSTEMS="hfs ufs apfs"
```

Assuming the file follows the convention of presenting the default settings as commented-out examples, it seems that *everything* located on HFS, UFS or APFS filesystems will be indexed by default, except the contents of `/tmp` and `/var/tmp`.

If the directory you wish to add is located on one of those filesystem types, and is not under `/tmp` or `/var/tmp`, the directory should automatically get indexed the next time `locate.updatedb` runs.

Note that many variants of `locate` will check for access permissions when displaying the results, and will only show you files you would have permission to see.

Comment: I did some tests, and it seems that not all files on the (APFS) filesystem on macOS Big Sur 11.5.2 (Intel) are indexed - `locate` can find `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask/Casks/google-chrome.rb`, but not `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions/Casks/google-chrome-canary.rb`, and it can't seem to find contents in `~/my-custom-dir`.

Comment: According to the `locate.updatedb(8)` man page, the database is updated only *once a week* by default - did you run the update task manually for testing?

Comment: No, I didn't run `locate.updatedb` before the tests. But these brew tap dirs and `~/my-custom-dir` has been on my mac for months, so they should be indexed, right?

Comment: Hmm. Also, on macOS you can use the `mdfind` command that utilizes the Spotlight search engine and its databases, which might be a better option than relying on the very basic `locate`.

Comment: I found something interesting. When limiting search inside a large dir, like `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps`, `find -name ...` is as fast as `mdfind -onlyin ... -name`, and twice as fast as `locate ...` without limiting search scope.

Comment: Maybe `locate` is not too reliable on newer macOS versions and I should avoid using it?

Comment: Since Spotlight is the primary search engine on macOS and `locate` is just something that was inherited from macOS's BSD origins and probably hasn't received much attention, I think that's a good assumption to make.